# How to get the CPU architecture via Idapython?

Tags: ida, idapython

I was not able to find an API function to get the CPU architecture of the loaded binary. 
In `idaapi.py`, there is a function `def set_processor_type(*args)` but no equivalent such as `get_processor_type`.

I don't want to fall back to running some additional (python) tool such as file, readelf or a python ELF parser. I also don't like the idea of parsing the strings displayed at the beginning of the IDA assembly listing.

There must be a way to use `idc.py`, `idaapi.py` or `idautils.py` for this.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this old thread, but for reasons I'm unable to figure out, both info.is_64bit() and info.is_32bit() are not working for me. I'm using IDA C++ SDK v7.1. Even if the executable in the database is 64-bit, it still goes through the 32-bit check. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15395)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the name of the processor from the `idainfo` struct:

```
import idaapi

info = idaapi.get_inf_structure()

if info.is_64bit():
    bits = 64
elif info.is_32bit():
    bits = 32
else:
    bits = 16

try:
    is_be = info.is_be()
except:
    is_be = info.mf
endian = "big" if is_be else "little"

print 'Processor: {}, {}bit, {} endian'.format(info.procName, bits, endian)
# Result: Processor: mipsr, 32bit, big endian
```

Still haven't found the endian, though.

EDIT:
Endian can be determined by processor name. For example, `mipsr` is big endian, and `mipsrl` is little endian.

EDIT:
Added a proper endian check (`mf` == MSB First). Based on [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11396/how-to-get-the-cpu-architecture-via-idapython/14326#14326).

EDIT:
Since IDA7 beta 3 (170724), idainfo.mf was removed, and idainfo.is_be() must be used. Based on [keypatch](https://github.com/keystone-engine/keypatch/blob/bfcaef11de3a90efb08ed4f0c39dccf40d5613d0/keypatch.py#L171-L177)

Answer (score 3):

Not all processor name has endian information. Generally it can be determinded as:

```
BIG_ENDIAN if _idaapi.cvar.inf.mf else LITTLE_ENDIAN
```

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not exact answer, but probably you could make use of

```
idaapi.ph_get_regnames()
```

> Returns the list of register names as defined in the processor module

Different platforms has different register sets, and if you will not find your solution about exact cpu you can give it a try.
This function exists in IDA 6.8.