# IDA Pro SDK APIs inf.is_64bit() and inf.is_32bit() are not working as expected!

Tags: idapro-sdk

As per this already answered question [How to get the CPU architecture via Idapython?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11396/how-to-get-the-cpu-architecture-via-idapython), for reasons I'm unable to figure out, both inf.is_64bit() and inf.is_32bit() are not working for me. I'm using IDA C++ SDK v7.1. Even if the executable in the database is 64-bit, it still goes through the 32-bit check. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What CPU architectures have you tested? x86/amd64, ARMv7/ARMv8a, or something else?

Comment: The sample I'm testing is a 64-bit Windows executable file loaded into the 64-bit version of IDA. So, if I run both APIs on it, they both return True!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. To determine if the binary is

- 32-bit: (inf.is_32bit() && !inf.is_64bit())
- 64-bit: (inf.is_64bit() && inf.is_32bit())

---

As of IDA 8.x you can find the following in `ida.hpp` which clarifies the above (trimmed to be more concise):

```
// unfortunately the name inf_is_32bit was used in the past to mean inf_is_32bit_or_higher.
// it was misleading, this is why we have more explicit names now.
bool inf_is_32bit_or_higher(void);
bool inf_is_32bit_exactly(void);
```

Comment: I recall this breaking something in RetDec, saw a ticket for this on GitHub, IIRC.